# Can I replace capacitor with multiple lower value capacitors in filter?

Tags: capacitor, filter

Can I replace higher capacitance value MLC capacitor in Sallen-Key topology filter with 2-3 lower value capacitors in parallel (with total capacitance equal to replaced cap)? I tried it in TINA-TI and AC Transfer characteristics are identical. Are there any contraindications to this?

The filter is 0.6..6.4Hz band pass. I started designing it using application report with basic equations, then did a lot of changes to adjust transfer characteristics. Changes include using capacitors with values not available on market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the parallel capacitances sum to the capacitance of the replaced capacitor there is no difference in the circuit. This is typically done in order to get a non-standard capacitance value out of standard capacitance values. For example, if you need \$8.6\mu\$F then you can put two standard \$4.3\mu\$F capacitors in parallel to get it since \$8.6\mu\$F is not a standard value.